# Extract string from within a longer string | Ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to extract a sentence from a long string using Ruby.

Example:

> Hi There the file is in this directory: **/Volumes/GAW-FS01/08_Video/02_Projects/ Plus/S/metadata.xml** Thank you for your inquiry.

It should return: */Volumes/GAW-FS01/08_Video/02_Projects/ Plus/S/metadata.xml*
The beginning always include "/Volume" and it has ti end with ".xml"

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide an attempt in code.

Comment: So basically `string[%r[/Volumes/.*/\.xml]]`?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for this -

```
long_string = <<file
Hi There the file is in this directory: /Volumes/GAW-FS01/08_Video/02_Projects/Plus/S/metadata.xml Thank you for your inquiry.Hi There the file is in this directory: /Volumes/GAW-def/08_Video/02_Projects/Plus/S/metadata.xml Thank you for your inquiry.Hi There the file is in this directory: /Volumes/GAW-FS01/08_Video/02_Projects/hello/S/metadata.xml Thank you for your inquiry.
file

long_string.split.select{ |word| word.starts_with?("/Volumes") && word.end_with?(".xml") }
```

It'll give you array of paths which match your condition like follow -

```
["/Volumes/GAW-FS01/08_Video/02_Projects/Plus/S/metadata.xml", "/Volumes/GAW-def/08_Video/02_Projects/Plus/S/metadata.xml", "/Volumes/GAW-FS01/08_Video/02_Projects/hello/S/metadata.xml"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

```
string = "Hi There the file is in this directory: /Volumes/GAW-FS01/08_Video/02_Projects/ Plus/S/metadata.xml Thank you for your inquiry."
```

Funky:

```
"Volume#{string[/Volume(.*?).xml/, 1]}.xml"
```

Funkier, find the index of the strings and use the range to return the desired string

```
first = "Volume"
last = ".xml"
string[(string.index(first)) .. (string.index(last) + last.length)]
 => "Volumes/GAW-FS01/08_Video/02_Projects/ Plus/S/metadata.xml "
```

Not so funky, split the string by the start and end points and return the desired string

```
"Volume#{string.split('Volume').last.split('.xml').first}.xml"
 => "Volumes/GAW-FS01/08_Video/02_Projects/ Plus/S/metadata.xml"
```

Lastly, the way you'd probably want to do this

```
string[/Volume(.*?).xml/, 0]
=> "Volumes/GAW-FS01/08_Video/02_Projects/ Plus/S/metadata.xml"
```

You notice the first and last options are the same, despite the int passed changing between 0 and 1. The 0 captures the regular expressions used to match where the 1 does not.